# Disable Shift Cmd Q for logout

Tags: keyboard, emacs, user-account

I would like to disable  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> keyboard shortcut for Log Out.

I am using **Karabiner** at the moment, but I only managed to disable it completely using the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Disable COMMAND SHIFT Q for Logout</name>
        <identifier>disable_CMD_SHIFT_Q_private</identifier>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Q, VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

but I would like to have the keyboard combination available in **emacs** (in ESS for debugging).

Is there some way that I can effectively unmap the keyboard combination?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following works for me on 10.9.5:

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.
2. '+' to add a shortcut
3. Application: `All Applications`
4. Menu Title: `Log Out [Your Name]…`  Here, copy the exact text shown in the Apple menu, replacing `[Your Name]`, and note that the ellipsis `…` must be typed with <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>
5. Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> (or whatever you prefer: something different to <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>)
6. Log out and in again.
7. Note that the keyboard shortcut has changed in the Apple menu, and <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> no longer triggers the menu.

Comment: Works perfectly. Very good to remember that the system shortcuts can be modified even if they are not visible in Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: Works for me as well on Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: This is not working for me on Sierra. I ensured the text is identical, and actually tried both regular ... and Alt key combination. But shortcut remains the same, unfortunately.

Comment: I was able to get this to work on High Sierra by doing the above for BOTH `Log Out <Your Name>` and `Log Out <Your Name>…`. Weirdly enough, by default High Sierra shows just `Log Out <Your Name>…`. If you override this shortcut as described, *another* item  appears in the "Apple" menu, this time without the ellipsis: `Log Out <Your Name>`, and having the same cmd_shift_q shortcut. Only when you override this second item can you truly free up cmd_shift_q.

Comment: Works for me on Catalina 10.15.5. I used this technique to enable control-command-Q as a shortcut in iTerm2.

Comment: Works for me on Monterey -- used to remap "Lock Screen" away from ctrl-cmd-Q so I can use that in emacs.

Comment: Doesn't work on Sonoma, menu item displays the new shortcut but shift cmd q still works even after log out and log in

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it because it is system shortcut. But you can add another shortcut over it. I found useless command to link with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

1. Go System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts

[image]

2. Select Accessibility and activate Zoom section by clicking box.

[image]

3. Select "Turn focus following on or off" and hit the "Add Shortcut" button.

[image]

4. Add <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> command to this shortcut.

[image]

You done.

Now <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut is useless.

Source https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7634486

Comment: It's simply not working on Sonoma