# Disable Command-Control-Q shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've a MacBook w/ the following specs:

[image]

Very annoyingly, <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> locks the screen. I can't even remap it to anything else; trying to do so in *Keyboard* locks the screen instead of registering the key combination.

Is there a way to get rid of this shortcut?

Comment: Ah...yes, the solution for the other question works here as well. Apparently this also means that Mac commands can only have 1 keyboard shortcut? _Weird_...

Answer (score -1):

It's a system-reserved key combination so you won't be able to remap it.

Comment: Hmmm.. I got a downvote for giving the correct answer?

Comment: It's possible to remap the key combination by using the technique here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210517/disable-shift-cmd-q-for-logout. I just did this successfully for control-command-Q in iTerm2.