# Disable Cmd Shift Q for cs go, cannot select it in keyboard pref

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

How can i disbable Command + Shift + Q for cs go, i can't figure it out. I use it for slow walking, ducking and moving around.

I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

I already tried this solution: [Disable Shift Cmd Q for logout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210517/disable-shift-cmd-q-for-logout) (accepted answer)

I seems to work when in steam, or chrome, or ... but not when in cs go.  You can only select steam under applications.

Update: I think i can fix this if the csg_osx64 unix executable can be added to "App Shortchutst" and overwrite the Log Out ... But can't add it , any ideas? (Location: /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo_osx64)

Comment: add a custom one for cs go, if you've added a global one

Comment: But where is it located, you can only select steam under applications.

Comment: Use easyfind to search it https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12 I don't use steam so I didnt know that

Comment: "/Users/msgt/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive" But this nee to be an .app file i think

Comment: now scroll down in app list and select other

Comment: I can get to the folder, but can't select it. I think it only accept .app files.

Comment: Try drag and drop

Comment: Doesn't work, but doesn't seam to work in steam aswell. It works in chrome. I'll keep you posted. Adding it on steam.app now.

Comment: use @ankii to notify me. (I don't get emails though, so will check tomorrow )

Comment: @ankii i can confirm ti works for steam.app now. But not for csgo_osx64. I can't select this. Found some info here https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/357287935563663541/

Comment: I can confirm this works form me: Quit csgo_osx64 mapping to other shortcut. I will post an update after testing! => It doest not, sorry!